# Distinct not working in ODM Querybuilder and Symfony 2.4

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I'm using this code:

```
    $languages = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Language')
    ->distinct('name')
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

And I'm getting this error:

ContextErrorException: Warning: MongoDB::command() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was using an old version of the php extension for mongodb, that was the issue.